# How to refactor switch statement with convoluted if chain within vuex module

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So this is my scenario. In my Websocket Vuex module I'm dealing with all the data coming from the server. I can get different kinds of notifications from the server and according to the type of notification I have to dispatch different actions, then for certain kind of notifications I have an array of events that I also have to evaluate in order to do something (usually dispatch more actions).

At the moment I'm using a switch statement in order to evaluate all the notifications and events but it's getting really convoluted and I'd love to use something as object literals or maps to try to improve my code.

This is what I have right now in my websocket vuex module action, this happens whenever I get a message from the server:

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
  const socketData = JSON.parse(event.data);
  const socketDataNotificationType = socketData.type;
  if (
    socketData.connectionId &&
    socketData.connectionId !== state.connectionId
  ) {
    commit("SET_CONNECTION_ID", socketData.connectionId);
    dispatch("shifts/updateEventsSubscription", rootState.token.agentId, {
      root: true,
    });
  } else {
    **//this is where the convoluted code begins**
    switch (socketDataNotificationType) {
      case "incoming-chats-updated":
        dispatch("setIncomingChats", socketData.incomingChats);
        break;
      case "chat-updated": {
        const chatSession = socketData.chat;
        const chatEvents = chatSession.events;
        const chatState = chatEvents.length - 1;
        if (chatEvents[chatState].type === "ChatAgentAssigned") {
          dispatch("chatSession/fetchChatSession", chatSession, {
            root: true,
          });
        } else {
          if (chatEvents[chatState].type === "ChatEnded") {
            dispatch("chatSession/removeChatSession", chatSession.id, {
              root: true,
            });
          } else {
            console.log("Other Type of Event");
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see the first SWITCH is for "socketDataNotificationType" and then when that notification is equal to "chat-updated" I have to evaluate an events object which create a really convoluted if chain (that can easily become another SWITCH because there will be more events in the future).

Is there any way I can improve this code with object literals or mapping ? Any advice will be really appreciate.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. This question is currently in the close vote queue due to `Missing Review Context`. There are 2 things that could be causing this, the first is the title of the post, the title of the post should indicate what the code does rather than your concerns about the code. The second thing that could be causing this is the use of global variables such as `state` and `chatSession`. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Two places that you can simplify:

1. After checking the connection ID there is nothing left for that code path to do, so you can return immediately and remove a level of nesting from the remainder of the function.
2. The original code has (pseudo):

   ```
   if (...) {
   } else {
     if(...) {
     } else {
     }
   }
   ```

   which could be more succinctly written as:

   ```
   if (...) {
   else if (...) {
   } else {
   }
   ```

   However, my preference would be to at least use another `switch` statement, but you could also break this switch out into a separate function.

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    const socketData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    const socketDataNotificationType = socketData.type;
    if (
        socketData.connectionId &&
        socketData.connectionId !== state.connectionId
    ) {
        commit("SET_CONNECTION_ID", socketData.connectionId);
        dispatch("shifts/updateEventsSubscription", rootState.token.agentId, {
            root: true,
        });
        
        // NOTE: There is no further code path for this case, so we can return and
        // remove a level of nesting from the remainder of the code
        return
    } 
    
    // **this is where the convoluted code begins**
    switch (socketDataNotificationType) {
        case "incoming-chats-updated":
            dispatch("setIncomingChats", socketData.incomingChats);
            break;
        case "chat-updated": {
            const chatSession = socketData.chat;
            const chatEvents = chatSession.events;
            const chatState = chatEvents.length - 1;
            
            // NOTE: Use another switch instead of if/else if/else
            
            switch (chatEvents[chatState].type) {
                case "ChatAgentAssigned":
                    dispatch("chatSession/fetchChatSession", chatSession, {
                        root: true,
                    });
                    break;
                    
                case "ChatEnded":
                    dispatch("chatSession/removeChatSession", chatSession.id, {
                        root: true,
                    });
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    console.log("Other Type of Event");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Many thanks @DaveMeehan, this was really useful. I ended up using an object literal and a ternary so I don't have to add multiple cases and just add properties to my object literal. But your code revision definitely helped.

Comment: @Lowtrux Perhaps post an update with your solution, for the benefit of others?  I was going to suggest also looking at a 'dispatch table', potentially an object with props matching what appears in the `case` statements, with the prop value being a function that contains the code.  Depending on how structured, this can create issues with access to variables in outer scope, but also can be easier to grok when the nesting/cases get unwieldy.